# US Visa process for children, how long does it take?

Tags: usa, visas, children

I'm not holding my hopes to high on getting an answer to this, but here goes... if you've ever applied for a non-immigrant US visa (specifically a B1, B2 or B1/B2 visa) you know that the normal process [I knew about] required the applicant to go to the embassy (or consulate) for an interview on a given date and at the end of that interview they would give you an answer as to whether you'd get the visa or not.

With some new process they started (not sure if across the globe or just here in Trinidad and Tobago) you fill a DS-160 form and then re-enter some data on [this site](https://usvisa-info.com/en-TT/selfservice/p), which will sort you through with the appointment part of the process, however, if you're applying for a kid under 14, you don't go to the embassy, rather, you send all the documents through DHL to them and they will only update you once they've shipped back the documents to you (even worse this update will only show up AFTER they've sent the documents back).

So reaching to the question at hand, I sent the documents 1 week ago, Today there's still no update on the site, I fear that emailing and asking them for a status update my cause them to reject the visa out of 'nagging spite' (since "common knowledge" indicates that Visa officers will reject you if they're having a bad day, etc). Has anybody experienced this process? or have any ideas as to how long this process will take? since the day I sent the visa application to now, the tickets for my group have gone up US$400+ at this rate I might not be able to travel (my dates can't be changed)...

Comment: Do you know what that site actually is?  As far as I can tell the official [DS-160 application](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/) isn't where you completed it.

Comment: I know, it's a different site altogether, but it's a site they sent you to... I emailed them a letter with some feedback to this new process. To answer your question, it's legit, you get sent there from http://trinidad.usembassy.gov/how_to_apply3.html

Comment: Not me.  The site I am being sent to is the one I linked.  May be it's source IP dependent though.  You should have an Application ID, so you can use my site to check what the status is of the application.

Comment: @Karlson: probably, but for me it was a the site you linked for the DS-160, and then the other site for the appointment, it's VERY confusing, not to mention the second site's design looks like a scam site, I pointed this out to them, I also made sure and clicked directly from the embassy's site about 3 times before accepting it as an official site

Comment: @rantsh: which embassy is responsible for you?

Comment: @Jonas Trinidad and Tobago's

Comment: @rantsh: hm, turns out it doesn't matter. Well, from what I can find, the procedure should be done "within 60 days of application" - not very helpful

Comment: So you sent only your childs documents right ? Are you and your wife stamped with a b1/b2 ?

Comment: @happybuddha yes, my wife and I have had visas for years, my kids were born after our last trip to the US

Comment: @rantsh Alright then, yours is a fairly straight forward case. Send them an email _demanding_ for the status. They are bound by law to give you an update. If the mail dont work, call the travel.state.gov office in the US asking for an update. If they had to get irked by every mail or phone call they received, they'd be mad every evening. :)

Comment: @happybuddha: "They are bound by law to give you an update": Citation needed.

Answer (score 4):

So I got my children visas yesterday, it ended up taking the better part of 10 days to get it back.

As a reference, they never updated anything on the profile on usvisa-info.com site until it was ready to be picked up at DHL, the message is quite minute and not highlighted at all